# Finding and Outputing multiple entries in an excel array

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a more complicated spreasheet but will explain what I am trying to do with a simpler spreadsheet.
I have 2 columns, the first column has First Names and the second column has Last Names.

For example:

```
Column1
Michael;
Michael;
Michael;
George;
Michael;
Henry;       

Column 2
Keaton;
Douglas;
Jackson;
Washington;
Jordan;
Ford;
```

I would like to create either an excel formula or vba function to search Column 1 for all the rows that match "Michael" and return all the Last Names associated with those "Michael" first names.  Preferably, concatenating the last names together with a space in between.  Vlookup, Index, Match, and Array functions in excel won't work because they only return the first "Michael" last name.  I have tested the VBA function below and it seems to work but would like feedback on this function or suggestions on a formula that would work.

So the output of the function for the above columns would be:

" (Keaton) (Douglas) (Jackson) (Jordan)"

Any help or suggestions would be welcome.

VBA code.
SourceArray would be the First Names, ID is "Michael", TargetArray is the Last Names.

```
Public Function DrawID(arrInput As Variant, ID As String, arrOutput As Variant)
Dim ArraySize As Integer
Dim i As Integer

ArraySize = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(arrInput)
i = 1
Do While i <= ArraySize
    If arrInput(i) = ID Then
        DrawID = DrawID & " (" & arrOutput(i) & ")"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Try this .. http://www.s-anand.net/blog/user-defined-array-functions-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Seams you need a Pivot Table. Give it a try.

To get `firstname lastname`, I suggest you to add a third column with concatenation (eg: <kbd>C1</kbd>`=A1&" "&B1`)